# How can the web page with Spring Boot load images from imgur?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, imgur

My web page would ajax(GET) and get the blog data from RESTFul backend.

After I got the data, my js program would update the page.

The data I got contained HTML tag, like:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg">
```

But after updated my web page, the 403 error was appeared because the images can not be obtain from imgur.

My web page was updated successfully except the images didn't load.

This is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/*.*", "/getPost/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/tinymce/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()

                .formLogin()
                    //.loginPage("/Login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()

                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.customUserDetailService)
        .passwordEncoder(this.getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*", "https://i.imgur.com"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thought i solved it...

If I used http://127.0.0.1, the images from imgur could not be obtain.

But I was successful if I used real IP to connect my website.